# safe to touch data after migrating to high replication datastore before another incremental copy?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

in order to migrate our application (2 years old, fair amount of data), I plan to use the [recommended tool](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration.html).

Some of our entities store serialized dictionaries with references to keys, so we'll need to convert those to change the application name part of the key. My question is, will changing data that has been migrated mess up the migration tool's understanding of what needs to be migrated during an incremental copy?  E.g, is it safe to:

- Start the migration tool
- run our custom tool to migrate stored keys (in the new app)
- verify our app works
- run an incremental copy
- run our tool again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that during the migration, the target app is in read only mode, so running any repair tools on the target hrd app before the migration is complete is not an option.

Instead, my approach is now to monkey patch db.get to rewrite keys on the fly, and then repair the references in the target app post migration. So far I've verified my new hrd app works fine with the monkey patch in place. It makes me wary to have to fix the references once the new version is live, but so it goes.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
import os

APP_ID = os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID')

def replace_key(key_str, app_id=None):
    app_id = app_id or APP_ID
    oldkey = db.Key(key_str) if not isinstance(key_str, db.Key) else key_str
    if oldkey.app() != app_id:
        fixedkey = str(db.Key.from_path(oldkey.kind(), oldkey.id_or_name(), _app=app_id))
        logging.info("rewriting %s to %s", str(oldkey), fixedkey)
        return fixedkey
    else:
        return key_str

old_get = db.get

def monkeyed_get(keys, **kwargs):
    single = False
    if isinstance(keys, (basestring, db.Model, db.Key)):
        single = True
        keys = [keys]

    results = old_get(map(lambda k: replace_key(str(k)), keys), **kwargs)
    return results[0] if single else results

db.get = monkeyed_get
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason we put the target app read-only is to prevent things like your taskqueues or cron jobs from running on partially copied data which could yield bad data in your target app.

It is possible to manually put the target datastore in read-write mode or to write a custom MR which uses datastore options which override the read-only setting to fix up your serialized entities as part of the process.

The migration tool only looks for changes in the Master/Slave application and then blindly copies them to the HRD application.  If you make changes in the HRD application they will be overwritten if changes are made to the same entity in your Master/Slave app.

That being said, I actually favor your approach which supports both and fixes the keys on demand.  You could also write a MapReduce to fix up any references that have not been fixed by this method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - good to know that read/write can be overridden before the migration is finalized. But like you recommend, once I worked within the constraints of read/only, it actually seemed like a cleaner approach. Our migration has been completed successfully.